show a toast for private route when user not logged in
I'm trying to show a toast to alert users who haven't logged in but tried to change the URL to get to other pages.
I'm using toast from sonner.
import { useEffect } from 'react'
import { Outlet, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'
import Cookies from 'universal-cookie'
import { toast } from 'sonner'

const PrivateRoute = () => {
  const cookie = new Cookies(null, { path: '/' })
  const navigate = useNavigate()

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!cookie.get('token')) {
      toast.error('You are not authorized to access this page')
      navigate('/login', { replace: true, })
    }
  }, [navigate])

  return <Outlet />
}

export default PrivateRoute


What is the problem, the code displays the toast and redirects when the is logged-in instead of when the user is not? Please [edit] to clarify the problem.

@DrewReese I apologize. It's my fault. I've adjusted it.
My problem is I want to show a toast to users if they change the URL to access other pages when they haven't logged in yet.

Code seems fine to me. How are users changing the URL? Can you [edit] to include your router & routes, and where/how users are changing the URL or navigating around your app, assuming that is what you mean?

The PrivateRoute component only checks the stored cookie once when the component mounts. I suspect you meant for this check to happen after any navigation action, i.e. when the app URL path changes. For this you can use the useLocation hook and add the location or location.pathname as dependency.
Example:
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { Outlet, useLocation, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import Cookies from 'universal-cookie';
import { toast } from 'sonner';

const PrivateRoute = () => {
  const { pathname } = useLocation();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  useEffect(() => {
    const cookie = new Cookies(null, { path: '/' });

    if (!cookie.get('token')) {
      toast.error('You are not authorized to access this page');
      navigate('/login', { replace: true });
    }
  }, [pathname, navigate]);

  return <Outlet />;
};

